# Why is it possible to print an array but not an array of structs with gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

I have written a python function for gdb to print an
array to save me time,to type the same line everytime.

```
define print_array
    print *($arg0)@(sizeof($arg0)/ sizeof($arg0[0])
end
```

It works like expected, but when I try to print an array of structs, I get the following error :

```
>>> print_array opcode_list 
A syntax error in expression, near `'.
>>>
```

When I type it by hand, it works without errors.

```
>>> print *(opcode_list)@(sizeof(opcode_list)/sizeof(opcode_list[0]))
$2 = {[0] = {
    opcode_str = 0x401484 "halt", 
    output = 0
  }, [1] = {
    opcode_str = 0x401489 "pushc", 
    output = 1
  }, ...
```

Could someone explain me, what is my fault?
And also give me maybe a hint/better solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing a `)`.

```
define print_array
    print *($arg0)@(sizeof($arg0)/ sizeof($arg0[0]))
end
```